# Replace task doesn't support nested fileset

Tags: java, ant

I'm running this content using Ant version 1.7.1:

```
<fixcrlf srcdir="@{buildDir}"   excludes="**/*.exe" eol="lf">
</fixcrlf>
<replace>
    <fileset dir="@{buildDir}" includes="**/*install.ksh" />
    <replacefilter token="#packageName#" value="@{packageName}"/>
</replace>
```

An exception is thrown with the message "replace doesn't support the nested "fileset" element"

What is the reason for this exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`<replace>` task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html) forms an implicit fileset, so you don't need to nest one in the way you have.  Try this instead, note how the `dir` and `includes` have been moved from a nested element to become parameters of the task:

```
<replace dir="@{buildDir}" includes="**/*install.ksh">
    <replacefilter token="#packageName#" value="@{packageName}" />
</replace>
```

or alternatively:

```
<replace dir="@{buildDir}">
    <include name="**/*install.ksh" />
    <replacefilter token="#packageName#" value="@{packageName}" />
</replace>
```